# c# - sharing a folder on local network

Tags: c#, networking, sharing

I try to share a folder on local network for a special group. 
I create the group, then I add the current user to this group. After this I share the folder on the local network with all the permisson to access to this for the group. In network I see the folder, all the permissons is granted for the group, it seems everything fine, but I can't access the folder on the local network.

I use this code:

```c#
 string ShareName = "SpecialShare";
 string Description = "This is a test";

 string folderPath = @"c:\ApplicationFolder\AppData";



try
        {
            NTAccount ntAccount = new NTAccount("SpecialGroup");

        SecurityIdentifier oGroupSID = (SecurityIdentifier)ntAccount.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
        byte[] utenteSIDArray = new byte[oGroupSID.BinaryLength];
        oGroupSID.GetBinaryForm(utenteSIDArray, 0);

        ManagementClass oGroupTrustee = new ManagementClass(new ManagementPath("Win32_Trustee"), null);
        oGroupTrustee["Name"] = "SpecialGroup";
        oGroupTrustee["SID"] = utenteSIDArray;

        ManagementClass oGroupACE = new ManagementClass(new ManagementPath("Win32_ACE"), null);
        oGroupACE["AccessMask"] = 2032127; //full access
        oGroupACE["AceFlags"] = AceFlags.ObjectInherit | AceFlags.ContainerInherit;
        oGroupACE["AceType"] = AceType.AccessAllowed;
        oGroupACE["Trustee"] = oGroupTrustee;

        ManagementObject oGroupSecurityDescriptor = new ManagementClass(new ManagementPath("Win32_SecurityDescriptor"), null);
        oGroupSecurityDescriptor["ControlFlags"] = 4;
        oGroupSecurityDescriptor["DACL"] = new object[] { oGroupACE };

        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("SpecialGroup", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

        ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

        //MessageBox.Show(managementClass.Derivation[0]);
        inParams["Description"] = Description;
        inParams["Name"] = ShareName;
        inParams["Path"] = folderPath;
        inParams["Type"] = 0; //Disk Drive
        inParams["MaximumAllowed"] = null;
        inParams["Password"] = null;
        inParams["Access"] = oGroupSecurityDescriptor;



        ManagementBaseObject outParams;
        outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

        if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
            throw new Exception();

        ManagementObject share = new ManagementObject(managementClass.Path + ".Name='" + ShareName + "'");
        share.InvokeMethod("SetShareInfo", new object[] { Int32.MaxValue, Description, oGroupSecurityDescriptor });

        dInfo.Refresh();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Better use impersonation rather than giving the users full permission.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

Comment: after your code is all said and done, are you able to see that the share is actually created and properly configured with the share + ntfs permissions?

Comment: Where in your code are you adding the user to the group?

Comment: I add the current user in another method. It works fine, in computer management I see the group, and the current user as group member.

Comment: And in the folder properties I see at share tab, that the group has read and write permissons, and by the advanced sharing the group has full permision. So I don't understand why can't access the folder on local network. Did I miss something?